# How can I determine the way to access certain third-party programs and resources from my Java app?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I'm trying to open a PDF file after I generate a report. I mean, the user logs in (it's a Swing-based app) and clicks to generate a report. Then, a PDF file is generated. I would like to launch the PDF reader at that moment. I could do something like `exec("evince "+path_to_pdf_file)`. It's just for Ubuntu, Windows would be more difficult. I'm thinking I need to explore the registry.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the method [java.awt.Desktop#open](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File))

> Launches the associated application to open the file.
>   If the specified file is a directory, the file manager of the current platform is launched to open it.